# How to get real data for Google Play Developer Console experiments?

Tags: developer-console, google-experiments

Is it possible to get real data (not scaled) for Google Play experiments?
Especially App store listing visitors and daily installs for variants. I would like to calculate Confidence level for experiment and I need those data for formula.